# adding openweather data to mapbox map

Tags: mapbox, openweathermap

So im trying to add weather data to my mapbox map. Im using for the data the openweather api. Im trying to add the data via adding a layer with the weather data tiles. Here's my current code: `    var map1 = "https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=e7fef929605b6a73c6921e4fec83f6ce"

```
map.on('load', function(){
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "simple-tiles",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": {
      "type": "raster",
      "tiles": ["https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/temp_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=e7fef929605b6a73c6921e4fec83f6ce"],
    "tileSize": 256
},
"minzoom": 0,
"maxzoom": 22
```

});
});`

So if i do it like this it works totaly fine, but if i try to add weather tileset trough a link provided on the openweather [website](https://openweathermap.org/api/weather-map-2#library) it doesnt work. Also the link is quiet different. For example i want to add this map: [http://maps.openweathermap.org/maps/2.0/weather/PA0/{z}/{x}/{y}?date=1527811200&appid={API](http://maps.openweathermap.org/maps/2.0/weather/PA0/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D?date=1527811200&appid=%7BAPI) key} it doesnt work. And yes i changed the api key placeholder with my api key. So any suggestions why its not working with this other link and how to fix that problem. Maybe iam just stupid but thanks in advance.